# strtok function in C programming

Tags: c

```
pch = strtok(str," ");
strcpy(piece1,pch);
printf("\n piece1 : %s \n",piece1);
while(pch != NULL){
        printf("\n %s \n",pch);
        pch = strtok(NULL," ");
        if(pch != NULL){
                strcpy(piece2,pch);
                printf("\n piece2 : %s \n",piece2);
        }
}
```

`strtok(str, " ")` fills up the space in the string with `'\0'`. what does the `strtok(NULL, " ")` do ? how does it split the remaining strings after getting the first token.

Comment: Per `man strtok`: *The  strtok() function parses a string into a sequence of tokens.  On the first call to strtok() the
       string to be parsed should be specified in str.  **In each subsequent call that should parse the  same
       string, str should be NULL.***

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about spoon-feeding the documentation for OP.


Comment: [strtok.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-166/string.subproj/strtok.c)

Answer (score 3):

`strtok` does some things that could be perceived of as dangerous.  Namely, when you call it and the first argument isn't `NULL`, it saves that argument and some other information in static variables (making it completely thread UNsafe).

As long as you keep passing null, it uses the same char array you originally passed it to look for more tokens.

Actually, more likely the implementation is that it saves the place it was in your string in a static variable.  It shouldn't care about where your string began; it only cares about where it is in your string.

Also, remember that `strtok` is changing the actual string you pass it, so if you needed that string to not have a bunch of '\0's in it, you should have made a copy of it before invoking `strtok`.